# This isn't normal right ? Required AM memory (471859200+47185920 MB) is above the max threshold (2048 MB)

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have read alot about solving that kind of problem by setting `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb`, which I have set to 2gb as I am currently running `select count(*) from <table>` which isn't a heavy computation, I guess. But what's `Required AM memory (471859200+47185920 MB)` supposed to mean? Other question says problem of about `(1024+2048)` or something like that.
I am setting up on a single machine, i.e my desktop which has 4-gb ram and 2 cores. Is this very low spec to run Spark as Hive execution engine? 
Currently I am running this job from java and my setup is

```
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://saurab:10000/default", "hiveuser", "hivepassword");
Statement state = connect.createStatement();
state.execute("SET hive.execution.engine=spark");
state.execute("SET spark.executor.memory=1g");
state.execute("SET spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=512m");
```

`yarn-site.xml`

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>3g</value>
</property>
```

And a simple query

```
 String query = "select count(*) from sales_txt";
 ResultSet res = state.executeQuery(query);
 if (res.next()) {
        System.out.println(res.getString());
     }
```

Also what are those two memory numbers (A+B) ?

Answer (score -1):

AM stands for Application Master for running Spark on Yarn. Good explanation here:
   https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/yarn/spark-yarn-applicationmaster.html

It's not clear why you need to run yarn on your single machine to test this out. You could run this in standalone mode to remove the yarn overhead, and test your spark application code. 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/

The `spark.*.memory` and `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` need to be set when you deploy the spark application. They cannot be set in those statements.